# How to use BERT for text classification in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

I am working on a text classification problem and would like to use the BERT model to improve my results. I have read about the BERT model but I am unsure about how to implement it in Python for my specific use case.

Here's the code I'm currently using with a simple logistic regression model:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

text_clf = Pipeline([
('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
('clf', LogisticRegression()),
])

text_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = text_clf.predict(X_test)
```

Can someone provide an example of how I might be able to replace this with a BERT model for text classification?